# query in objects with django orm with a containing sentence

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-orm

i have some city like this:

```
In [99]: City.objects.filter(title='Hamilton')
Out[99]: <QuerySet [<City: hamilton>]
```

i have some sentences like this:

sentence = '3101A 1280 Main Street West Hamilton ON  L8S 4K1'

how can i find cities that contains its title with this sentence?

Note: i have used this method but it is not True. because this query is useful for list not string in django:

```
In [100]: City.objects.filter(slug__in=sentence)
Out[100]: <QuerySet []>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Contains` lookup for *case-insensitive substring* search:

```
from django.db.models import F, Value
from django.db.models.lookups import Contains

City.objects.filter(Contains(Value(sentence), F('title')))
```

While using the [**`__icontains`** lookup <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#icontains) produces results for text, this often is still a poor way to search, since it will only fetch items with the exact string. Usually one uses solutions like [*Elastic*](https://www.elastic.co/) or [*Solr*](https://solr.apache.org/), or one can uses *PostgreSQL*'s [**`__search`** lookup <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#the-search-lookup).

Comment: you did not understand my issue. i have that sentence.

sentence = '3101A 1280 Main Street West Hamilton ON L8S 4K1'

Comment: @HosseinSayyedmousavi: ah yes, so the opposite way, like in the edit?